# Odoo 10 - Can't access Postgresql (9.5) via pgAdmin4 even with pg_hba.conf changes

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

Need access to the Odoo postgresql DB (via pgAdmin 4). Even with the changes made to pg_hba.conf it won't connect.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             [Our Networks IP]/32       md5
host    postgres        odoo            [Our Networks IP]/32       trust
host    SLWK_PRE-PROD_DB        odoo            [Our Networks IP]/32       md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Is my format wrong or am I missing something else? I've tried connecting via bash as a super user and it won't let me query stuff either.

I've already tried editing the pg_hba.config with different settings but no avail.

When trying to connect via pgAdmin 4 the following error appears:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[Our Networks IP]", user "odoo", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[Our Networks IP]", user "odoo", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by putting the AWS EC2 instance IP in the `pg_hba.conf` in the Unix-domain socket fields. Was putting my configuration in the TCP/IP part of the `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to restart PostgreSQL? You need to reload its configuration after making any changes to apply them.

The easiest way to do it is to restart PostgreSQL service:

```
service postgresql restart
```

You can also use pg_ctl:

```
sudo su postgres
pg_ctl reload
```

Or you can do inside PostgreSQL itself:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=> SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: Solved the issue by putting the EC2 IP in the `pg_hba.conf` in the Unix-domain socket fields. Was putting my configuration in the TCP/IP part of the `pg_hba.conf`